# Need help ensuring text shifted 'x' amount of spaces is transformed into letters, not random symbols

Tags: php, string, encryption, ascii, caesar-cipher

I'm working on a page on cryptography, and have decided to include a Caesar Cipher, a method in which you shift a letter 'X' amount of spaces left or right. Example: Encrypting the letter 'A' with a shift parameter of 2. A => C.

The code below is working somewhat decently. It's able to encrypt/decrypt the text I enter, as long as it's between certain ASCII values.

The values 65-90 in ASCII is uppercase letters, and 97-122 is lowercase letters. My problem is if my shift parameter is so large, that I exceed these intervals.

Let's say I have the letter 'A' which I want to encrypt with a shift parameter of 100. If I try this, the letter 'A' becomes this character (http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-codes/spanish-enye-capital-letter-n-tilde-enie-uppercase-ascii-code-165.gif), which can't show up in my browser, and is converted into a weird question mark.

My question is, what are my options for avoiding these weird symbols? Is it possible to make it so it only includes letters (uppercase and lowercase) and maybe numbers as well?

I hope you can help me. I will be online all day, so if you need any more information, just ask :-)

My form field:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="textCaesarEncrypt" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Indtast tekst">
<input type="number" name="shiftCaesarEncrypt" autocomplete="off">
<label>Krypter</label>
<input type="radio" name="caesarEncryptOrDecrypt" value="caesarEncrypt">
<label>Dekrypter</label>
<input type="radio" name="caesarEncryptOrDecrypt" value="caesarDecrypt">
<input type="submit" name="submitCaesarEncrypt" value="Videre">
```

My PHP:

```
    <?php
        $caesarEncryptOrDecrypt = $_POST ["caesarEncryptOrDecrypt"];

     if (!empty($_POST['textCaesarEncrypt']) AND 
     !empty($_POST['shiftCaesarEncrypt'])){

$string = $_POST['textCaesarEncrypt'];
$shift = $_POST['shiftCaesarEncrypt'];
$shiftedString = "";


if($caesarEncryptOrDecrypt == "caesarEncrypt") {
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
        $ascii = ord($string[$i]);
        $shiftedChar = chr($ascii + $shift);

        $shiftedString .= $shiftedChar;
    }
    echo $shiftedString;
}

if($caesarEncryptOrDecrypt == "caesarDecrypt") {
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
        $ascii = ord($string[$i]);
        $shiftedChar = chr($ascii - $shift);

        $shiftedString .= $shiftedChar;
    }
    echo $shiftedString;


}

}   
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's important to mention that [Caesar-Cipher **is not recommended**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher#Breaking_the_cipher), it's too weak, **weak**, weak, **too weak** and pretty easy to be broken.

for sure you don't want to use an encrypting system which was used before more that 2000 years

> **Julius Caesar**: 13 July 100 BC – 15 March 44 BC)

---

However, The key here is in the up next formula -in the encrypting case-:

[image]

while to decrypt your encrypted data , you will need to use the next formula :

[image]

where En(x) refers to encrypted char, x = char, n = shift value;

[formulas images source [wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher#Example)

---

However this formula is pretty good for humans, but not for computers , humans only have 26 Latin character, while computers have ASCII which represented by 128, also we don't care about the case of the letter, so Hello = heLLo for us, while it is not the same with computers which represents a as 97 and A as 65.

so you will need to convert your ASCII to easy 1-26 range of character.

here i will implement a simple edit in your encrypting part, and I hope that helps you to implement the rest of decrypting part of your code.

```
for ($i = 0, $n = strlen($string); $i < $n; $i++) {
    $char = $string[$i];
    // here we are checking the character type
    // to set the range which will be used later
    if (ctype_upper($char)) {
        $range = 65;
    } else if (ctype_lower($char)) {
        $range = 97;
    }
    // convert the ascii indexed chars into alphabetic indexed chars
    $ascii = ord($char) - $range;
    // the caesar folrmula based on alphabetic indexed chars
    $shiftedChar = chr((($ascii + $shift) % 26) + $range);
    $shiftedString .= $shiftedChar;
}
echo $shiftedString;
```

If you want to make sure that only alphabetic characters will be encoded, you may use [ctype_alpha](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php) to check that, it's returns true if the character is alphabetic chars.

It's also important to notice that in decrypting Caesar-cipher , you will need as mentioned before to use the next formula :

```
$shiftedChar = chr((($ascii - $shift) % 26) + $range);
//                          ^ notice this
```

also to change your ranges as follows :

```
if (ctype_upper($char)) {
    $range = 90; // start with Z
} else if (ctype_lower($char)) {
    $range = 122; // start with z
}
```

---

another great helpful source [from cs50](http://docs.cs50.net/problems/caesar/caesar.html) , this is a Caesar-cipher C tutorial , but it has the same concept.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at it.
I'm aware of it not being very secure, I'm only doing this to demonstrate how it works. I also have an example with RSA (which is becoming outdated as well), but it's more to demonstrate how it works, I'm not really using it for anything else :)

Comment: I think I figured it out for the decrypt part. I reversed the ranges, so instead of 65 for A and 97 for a, it is 90 for Z and 122 for z. I also changed $shiftedChar = chr((($ascii + $shift) % 26) + $range);, so it now says $ascii - $shift. It seems to work, but would like to know if this is how you would've done it as well? :)

Comment: @@HassanThank you very much, this is just what I was looking for! I think I'll use this when I get to RSA as well, to avoid the non-supported symbols :-)

Comment: you are welcome, if i got what you mean i think in the Caesar-Cipher context using ctype_alpha will avoid you non-alphabetical symbols issues

Comment: I might do that later, it works fine now, and I'ma bit short on time, so I'll stick with it for now. Got another problem though:

I moved on to RSA and used some of the things you helped me with, to encrypt with RSA instead. Right now it works with 1 letter, but if I write 'ab', it'll only run the letter 'b' through the code (or so it seems). 
I think I have to split the message into an array, and run every letter through, one by one (maybe with array_walk?).

Comment: @@hassan To use array_walk, I think I have to make my some of my code into functions, which is where my problem lies right now. I've never made a function, except for some very easy ones, so I'm struggling a bit. I watched a tutorial and, while it helped me understand it better, it didn't solve my problem.
I've edited my post with my function (which isn't working)

Comment: Nevermind, my function was correct, I'd just forgotten a closing bracket :P

Comment: 'I think I have to split the message into an array' you don't have to, fundamentally string is a sequence - array- of characters, so when in your for loop do like so `$string[$i]` you are treating your string as an array which is fundamentally right.

Comment: array_walk & array_map is such an equivalent to foreach or for loops

Comment: When I enter several letters, it only outputs it like this (http://imgur.com/a/bMi4m)

My code is in here if you want to check it out :) (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43665694/need-help-returning-a-variable-from-my-function)

Comment: as mentioned in the comment there, you need to get the return statement out of the loop

Comment: I did that already, right now it's after I close the for loop, but before I close the function. Is that the correct placement? Like so (http://i.imgur.com/VNtqIqO.png)
I still get nothing when I try echoing it, so I guess it's still wrong..

Comment: yes, but forget the variable inside your function, as you are returning a value from your function, you need to assign this function to another variable like so : `$encrypted = encryptRSA($message);echo $encrypted;`

Comment: I think that it would be better to stop talking about this issue here, as long as it does not related to the original issue, let's move our conversation to the other question if you still have issues :)

Comment: Yes, that seems like a good idea. There's a question waiting for you in there ;)

Comment: @@hassan, forgot to tag you :)