# Need help returning a variable from my function

Tags: php, function, encryption, return, rsa

I'm doing a program about RSA-encryption, and I have a problem right now. I can only encrypt 1-letter-messages (but does those as it should). 
What I think I need to do is splitting the message into an array, then using a command like array_walk, going through the code with each letter, one by one, then using implode to get it all back together at the end.

```
         <?php 
$p; //Først kalder jeg alle variablerne
$q;
$N;
$e;
$d;
$message;

$p = 2; //Derefter definerer jeg dem
$q = 11;
$N = $p*$q;
$e = 7;
$d = 13;
$message = "f";


echo "Public key (".$e.", ".$N.")<br><br>"; //Echoer min puclic key 
bestående af e og N

for ($i1 = 0; $i1 < strlen($message); $i1++) {
$char1 = $message[$i1];
if (ctype_upper($char1)) { //Checker om bogstaverne er store
    $range1 = 65-1; //Hvis de er, defineres range til 65-1
} else if (ctype_lower($char1)) { //Checker om bogstaverne er små
    $range1 = 97-1; //Hvis de er, defineres range til 97-1
}
$encryptedMessage = ord($char1) - $range1; //Konverterer beskeden til den 
tilsvarende ascii værdi - range
echo "Beskeden ".$message." laves om til tallet ".$encryptedMessage;
}
echo "<br>";

$ePowEncrypted = pow($encryptedMessage, $e);
echo "e = ".$ePowEncrypted."<br>";

$modEncrypted = fmod($ePowEncrypted, $N);
echo "String mod N = ".$modEncrypted."<br><br><br>";

echo "Private key (".$d.", ".$N.")<br><br>";

for ($i2 = 0; $i2 < strlen($message); $i2++) {
$char2 = $message[$i2];

if (ctype_upper($char2)) {
    $range2 = 90-1;
} else if (ctype_lower($char2)) {
    $range2 = 122-1;
}

$decryptedMessage = ord($char2) - $range2;
$shiftedChar = chr((($decryptedMessage) % 26) + $range2);
}



$ePowDecrypted = pow($encryptedMessage, $d);
$modDecrypted = fmod($ePowDecrypted, $N);
echo "Tallet ".$modDecrypted." laves om til bogstavet ".$shiftedChar;




?>
```

This is what I'm trying to make a function

```
<?php 
function encryptRSA($message) {
    for ($i1 = 0; $i1 < strlen($message); $i1++) {
        $char1 = $message[$i1];

        if (ctype_upper($char1)) { //Checker om bogstaverne er store
            $range1 = 65-1; //Hvis de er, defineres range til 65-1
      } else if (ctype_lower($char1)) { //Checker om bogstaverne er små
            $range1 = 97-1; //Hvis de er, defineres range til 97-1
        }

        $encryptedMessage = ord($char1) - $range1; //Konverterer beskeden 
      til den tilsvarende ascii værdi - range
        echo "Beskeden ".$message." laves om til tallet 
       ".$encryptedMessage;

        return $encryptedMessage;

}
}

$message = 'a';
encryptRSA($message);
?>
```

---

```
 <?php 
$p; //Først kalder jeg alle variablerne
$q;
$N;
$e;
$d;
$message;

$p = 2; //Derefter definerer jeg dem
$q = 11;
$N = $p*$q;
$e = 7;
$d = 13;
$message = "f";
echo "message = ".$message;
echo "<br><br>";


echo "Public key (".$e.", ".$N.")<br><br>"; //Echoer min puclic key bestående af e og N

include 'encryptFunction.php';

$encryptedText = encryptRSA($message);
echo "Beskeden ".$message." laves om til tallet ".$encryptedText;

echo "<br>";

$ePowEncrypted = pow($encryptedText, $e);
echo "e = ".$ePowEncrypted."<br>";

$modEncrypted = fmod($ePowEncrypted, $N);
echo "String mod N = ".$modEncrypted."<br><br><br>";

echo "Private key (".$d.", ".$N.")<br><br>";

for ($i2 = 0; $i2 < strlen($message); $i2++) {
$char2 = $message[$i2];

if (ctype_upper($char2)) {
    $range2 = 90-1;
} else if (ctype_lower($char2)) {
    $range2 = 122-1;
}

$decryptedMessage = ord($char2) - $range2;
$shiftedChar = chr((($decryptedMessage) % 26) + $range2);
}



$ePowDecrypted = pow($encryptedText, $d);
$modDecrypted = fmod($ePowDecrypted, $N);
echo "Tallet ".$modDecrypted." laves om til bogstavet ".$shiftedChar;

?>
```

And the document that contains the function

```
     <?php
function encryptRSA($message) {
    for ($i1 = 0; $i1 < strlen($message); $i1++) {
        $char1 = $message[$i1];

        if (ctype_upper($char1)) { //Checker om bogstaverne er store
            $range1 = 65-1; //Hvis de er, defineres range til 65-1
      } else if (ctype_lower($char1)) { //Checker om bogstaverne er små
            $range1 = 97-1; //Hvis de er, defineres range til 97-1
        }

        $encryptedMessage = ord($char1) - $range1; //Konverterer beskeden til den tilsvarende ascii værdi - range
}
    return $encryptedMessage;
}

?>
```

Comment: You have a return, but apparently, it's inside the for loop - so if the loop exits, the default return value is NULL. Better code formatting can help make this clearer. printing the output of `encryptRSA($message);` may also show something, instead of doing nothing with the call.

Comment: @AlisterBulman  Like so? (i.imgur.com/VNtqIqO.png) I still get nothing when I try echoing it, so I guess it's still wrong..

Comment: images aren't very helpful for code - and you have to collect the return value to be able to do with it. `$msg =  encryptRSA($message);  echo $msg;`  Also, append each new character to the end of the previous ones in the loop

Comment: @hassan, The encryption function works now, but for some reason, I can't get the decrypter working... I've edited my post with my current code. (I know I'm not doing much myself currently, but trust me, I'm trying to. I'm just getting stressed since my deadline for this project (my exam) is in a little less than 17 hours) :I